# Time machine specify destination folder

Tags: time-machine

Is there a way to do the time machine backup in a folder of the destination volume and not in its root?

I have a network attached storage that provides a shared volume. I would like to backup my Mac in a folder that other people cannot access.

I know that an option to avoid other people to see my data would be to encrypt the backup, but this is not what I'm looking for.